# Gemfile.lock not checked in - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bundler

While trying to "git push heroku master", I keep getting the error :

```
Counting objects: 266, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (239/239), done.
Writing objects: 100% (266/266), 222.68 KiB, done.
Total 266 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.3
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * version: 1.0.6
       FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:freezing-frost-65.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:freezing-frost-65.git'
```

I tried adding Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to git but to no avail. I tried removing .bundle directory and Gemfile.lock but the same error.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034561/should-gemfile-lock-be-committed-to-source-control-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer at - http://www.unityisplural.com/2010/11/hobo-finally.html

Answer (score 15):

There is a problem with bundler version 1.0.6
You need to run "gem update bundler" on your development machine to update bundler to 1.0.7. Then you need to run bundle update in your app to generate a new Gemfile.lock file. You will see that the Gemfile.lock is updated. Commit this new Gemfile.lock and push to heroku again.

Comment: Aditya, that is correct. I just removed the version tag and things worked fine for me. But I will try this approach also. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to run bundle update in your app to generate a new Gemfile.lock file.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed mine by opening Gemfile.lock and deleting the following two lines:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

So now i just need to make a script that bundles then removes that from the lock file.

Comment: This worked for me!  Seems Heroku will ignore your Gemfile.lock of these lines are present.

Answer (score 6):

Both the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files needs to be included in the git repository.
Make sure you are not ignoring them in the `.gitignore` file.

Also, make sure you are using Bundler >= 1.0.0 on your local machine to generate the `Gemfile.lock`. I you use an outdated version, such as Bundler 0.9x, it will fail.

Last but not least, update your Gemfile.lock if you have one.

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ bundle update
```

Comment: I did bundle update and my .gitignore does not have Gemfile or Gemfile.lock in it.

Comment: bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.6

Comment: @Ved: What matters is whether those files are present in the commit you're trying to push to heroku. You're pushing from your local repo, not from github. (Of course, maybe those are in sync; I wouldn't know.)

Comment: How do I find if these files are in the main branch ? I tried removing and readding them too.

Comment: Well this seems to be a complete blocker for me and for lot of other people (given the number of google hits and misses)

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the "mingw" line under PLATFORMS on my Gemfile.lock file, added and committed to git, pushed it to git, then pushed everything to heroku and apparently it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In your applicaton directory, in the `bin` subdirectory modify the files

```
bin/bundle 
bin/rails 
bin/rake
```

Instead of

```
'#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

must be

```
'#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

(thanks to previous post)

Make sure there are no references to windows in the gemfile.lock - they can just be deleted.

Then

```
git push heroku master
```

If there are still problems use `heroku logs` (copying text to a text editor makes it easier to cut and paste for solutions).