# Cant seem to push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am working with a rails app and I can't seem to be able to push my app to Heroku.  I have set up everything and use git but everytime I push it to heroku I get this:

```
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
   the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * therubyracer (>= 0.8.2)
   * libnotify
   * rb-inotify

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:
   * growl
   * rb-fsevent
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
```

!     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

I have noticed that my version of gem is 1.0.11 but the heroku push is using running Bundler version 1.0.7.  I dont know if this makes a difference but I don't know how to go back to an older version.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you failed to add your Gemfile.lock into the git repo for heroku.

Make sure it's not in your .gitignore, then:

```
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Adding Gemfile.lock"
```

Comment: I have tried this and have even tried starting over and adding the Gemfile.lock file but it still gives the above error.

Comment: This is a pretty old answer, but you could give it a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4302327/560803

Comment: Thanks, I did see that one.  I did have an error trying to update ffi to version 1.0.11 instead of 1.0.9 which I currently have.  I did however find another issue that may be causing the problem.  In my Gemfile I have it set up to run differently depending on the Server's OS, adding rubyracer etc. when its a Linux machine.  Could this be the issue?  I use a Mac in development and wasn't sure if this may be affecting the push since it seems like it is those files that are causing the error.

Comment: So I think that was it.  I deleted the conditionals and it worked fine.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have therubyracer in your Gemfile are you using Rails 3.1? You would be much better off running on the Cedar stack as opposed to the Bamboo stack. Cedar does not require the rubyracer gem to be in your gemfile. Bundler version doesn't matter in this case, 1.0.11 is used on Cedar whilst 1.0.7 is used on Bamboo but that's all managed by Heroku.

Comment: Yes I am using Rails 3.1. I still get this error after moving to the cedar stack.  Its strange because it tells me to run bundle install which I have done 100 times and then add the Gemfile.lock which I have done but then still gives me the same error.

Comment: are you using Windows by any chance?

Comment: Nope was on Mac, but I figured it out, was running conditionals based on the OS and that was holding me up.  Thanks