# Should Gemfile.lock be committed to source control on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, heroku

Ruby newb here.

I download ruby via rubyinstaller, did `gem install rails`, resolved a few missing libraries, and finally forked the [ruby project](http://selfstarter.us/) I want to work on.

Before touching anything, I see that my Gemfile.lock is modified:

```
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index aefda68..9ebccba 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -46,6 +46,7 @@ GEM
     diff-lcs (1.1.3)
     erubis (2.7.0)
     eventmachine (1.0.0)
+    eventmachine (1.0.0-x86-mingw32)
     execjs (1.4.0)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
     hike (1.2.1)
@@ -65,11 +66,17 @@ GEM
     multi_json (1.3.6)
     multi_xml (0.2.2)
     pg (0.14.1)
+    pg (0.14.1-x86-mingw32)
     polyglot (0.3.3)

...

 PLATFORMS
   ruby
+  x86-mingw32
```

All the modified lines seem to be Windows related. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151540/11236) seems to indicate that I should not gitignore Gemfile.lock (it's already committed to the repo I cloned anyway). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811182/11236) implies I might get errors if I do commit & push it to heroku (makes sense, since I don't want my app to depend on Windows-specific files).

So, which is it? How should I fix it? Should I delete Gemfile.lock from my repo?

Comment: Might want to try platforms in GEmfile, http://qastuffs.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-configure-gemfile-for-windows.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

Last time I pushed to Heroku with a Windows `Gemfile.lock` it handled it pretty gracefully. I don't remember if it failed and rebuilt the `Gemfile.lock` or just stripped the binary gem tags.

There are 2 viable options I see.
One is to assume that there isn't going to be a problem with this behavior. Which means using strict gem version requirements or updating your `bundle` and confirming everything works before you push.

Another is to use the [`:platform` flag in your Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-). I won't recommend this, but it should force the source down and compile the gem locally. Which means any external dependencies need to be available. With a lot of binary gems (like the `pg` gem) this isn't an easy task. With some other gems it can be nearly impossible. Once again, I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: I would like to avoid any modifications to the gemfile. I tried to submit a pull request to the project I forked, only to find out later that I had accidentally committed the gemfile. Even though it might not cause problems, gemfile-modification is certainly not part of what I'm trying to push back to them. Do either of these options work ? They both seem to require some modifications to the gemfile.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the question was what are the effects of the `Gemfile.lock` when deploying your application to a linux environment.

Comment: I looked at the [pull request](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/pull/22) I'm assuming you're talking about. Looks like you added a `pry` dependency and that changed the `Gemfile.lock`. Ironically you didn't commit the `Gemfile` changes just the `Gemfile.lock` changes. =P  I would just go back and remove the `Gemfile.lock` changes from the commits since the change was accidental anyway.